# Which keys does a client use for TLS communication?

Tags: ssl, debian, rsa, raspberry-pi3

A TLS sockets client is running on a Raspberry Pi under user "bob".  It connects to a socket server operating on Centos.  The server's keys are located at `/etc/pki/tls/private/sockets_key.pem` and `/etc/pki/tls/certs/sockets_crt.pem`.

Where are the client's keys located?

Comment: Which client keys? There is a client private key (and certificate) only if mutual authentication is used and where these are located depends on the client application. Or do you mean the root CA? From your question it looks like that you don't understand what a key in TLS is and where and when it is used since the second file you give is not a key but a certificate (which contains the public key matching the giving private key - but is not a key by itself).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich  I was referring to the certificate as the public key.  Sorry for the confusion.  Also, not asking about CA.  It is my understanding that the client also needs a public and private key, but maybe not?  I am running tshark on the client and wish to decrypt and analyze the transmission for troubleshooting purposes.

Comment: The client only needs a key pair if mutual authentication is done, i.e. usually not. I recommend to read [How does SSL/TLS work?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-tls-work). Also, decrypting a sniffed session by using the private key works only with RSA key exchange but mostly DH key exchange is used today. And with RSA key exchange you only need the servers private key and not the clients one even if mutual authentication is used.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich  Thanks.  Will read it.  While I have control over both machines, still curious how one could do so if they were only in control of the client.  If the client software has all the information to decrypt, then tshark/etc on the same machine must.